# Pressing Ctrl+D when the terminal is in raw mode

Tags: linux, shell, terminal

When the terminal is not in raw mode, if I write some text, this text will be placed in a buffer (I think it's called the **line buffer**), after that if I press `Ctrl+D`, the content of this buffer will be sent to my application.

But what happens when I press `Ctrl+D` and the terminal is in raw mode (i.e. what I write in the terminal is not buffered but rather it's sent directly to my application), will some ASCII code (probably `0x04`) be sent to my application?

Comment: Is this the third CTRL-D question of the day?  Is this a homework assignment?  Be honest.  Dup?

Comment: @RubberStamp It's the second `Ctrl+D` question. And no, it's not a homework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check that with `strace`

In shell 1:

```
$ echo $$
1234
```

In shell 2:

```
strace -p 1234 -f
```

In shell 1:

```
$ stty raw
$ cat
[type something including ^D]
```

In Shell 2 you can see:

```
[pid 12345] read(0, "\4", 131072)       = 1
```

Comment: Why is it that it is this way in raw-mode and it does not end the transmission, as in canonical mode?

Comment: @user129393192 I would say because this is the reason why there are both raw mode and canonical mode.

Comment: There are no more reason than that? I notice even raw mode certain control characters don't get through (perhaps some without disabling some signals), so I am wondering the motivation to make EOT not work and what specifically needs to be taken care of if the application makes use of Control characters.